# Could not download gradle-core.jar

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

My Android Studio cannot import gradle-core.jar.

The error message contained in the article,

```
Error: Could not download gradle-core.jar 
(com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:2.1.2): 
No cached version available for offline mode,
```

My android version is 2.2.2 and I use AMD processors, it makes me not able to install intel HAXM.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 10):

I recently faced the same issue. Do the following:

1. Go to Android Studio Settings -> Build Tools -> Gradle
   In project-level settings set "Use default gradle wrapper" on. Set the offline work named checkbox unchecked. and aapply changes.
2. Try to sync gradle. It will download the needed gradle-core.jar

Comment: for me also. I do not know why such idiotic errors come in android studio